# No envía datos desde php a mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, crud

Estoy usando CRUD para enviar datos desde la web a una base de datos en mysql, usando store procedures y no logro enviarlo, ¿cuál es mi error?

Aquí mi formulario html, estoy enviando datos con el método post

```
     <form action="../models/insertusuario.php" method="POST">
      
       <input type="text" name="apaterus" ><br/>
       <input type="text" name="amaterus" ><br/>
       <input type="text" name="nombresus" ><br/>
       <input type="number" name="DNIus" ><br/>
       <input type="text" name="cargo" ><br/>
       <input type="text" name="correoe" ><br/>
       <input type="password" name="contraseniaus"><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="cargar" value="CARGAR">
     </form>
```

Y donde enviaré los datos, creo que es aquí donde surge mi problema, pero no sé cómo identificarlo. Cuando ejecuto el procedimiento en mi gestor de base de datos sí los ingresa, pero desde aquí no.

```
    <?php
include "../config/database.php";

if (isset($_POST['cargar'])) {
  $apaterus      = $_POST['apaterus'];
  $amaterus      = $_POST['amaterus'];
  $nombresus     = $_POST['nombresus'];
  $DNIus         = $_POST['DNIus'];
  $cargo         = $_POST['cargo'];
  $correoe       = $_POST['correoe'];
  $contraseniaus = $_POST['contraseniaus'];
  
$sql= "CALL sp_insertar_usuarios('$apaterus','$amaterus','$nombresus','$DNIus','$cargo','$correoe','$contraseniaus')";

$resultado = mysqli_query($pdo,$sql);
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Te muestra algun error?

Comment: No, solo el resultado de if (!$resultado){
  die("Consulta fallida");
} Consulta fallida

Comment: Bien podemos empezar por eso, antes de enviar esos datos comprobaste que los los envie correctamente, de no ser asi haz un `var_dump($variable de tus datos)`

Comment: Antes de llamar al store procedure, lo que hice fue mostrar los datos que ingrese a los imput por pantalla a traves de un  echo, y los mostraba.

Comment: OK eso descarta los datos, el procedure esta bien ejecutado?

Comment: Sí claro, bueno, desde mysql puedo agregar datos tranquilo con el procedure. Pero cuando uso var_dump me sale server error 500, eso influye en algo?

Comment: Bien, ahora falta el codigo, por el codigo que veo no puedo decirte mucho podrias publicar mas por favor

Comment: Es todo el código que tengo, ya prové la conexión a la base de datos y eso está ok, igual cambié el procedimiento almacenado y puse INSERT INTO y nada.

Comment: <?php
 $servidor="mysql:dbname=MPCH;host=127.0.0.1";
 $usuario="root";
 $password="root";
                                                                                                                               
try {
  $pdo=new PDO($servidor,$usuario,$password);
  echo "Conectado";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "conexion mala".$e->getMessage();
}
 ?> Esta es mi conexión a la base de datos

Comment: Cuando una consulta no se ejecuta y no tira error de PDO significa que los datos ingresados por el codigo son incorrectos o falta un valor

Comment: Ya le estoy enviando todos los datos a la tabla, en mi consola de firefox me sale estado 200 que creo que es sin error, pero igual consulto a la tabla y no me aparece registro.

Comment: Si estás usando PDO no entiendo por qué mandas a ejecutar la consulta con `mysqli_query`, que es de la API `mysqli`y no tiene nada que ver con PDO. El método de consulta de PDO es `query`

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo estas utilizando PDO así que no te va a funcionar mysqli_query.
Y creo que te quedaría algo así, al menos para que tomes la idea de como va:

```
 <?php
    include "../config/database.php";
    if (isset($_POST['cargar'])) {
        try {
               //Los campos de tu base de datos
            $insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO sp_insertar_usuarios  (apaterus, amaterus, nombresus, DNIus, cargo, correoe, contraseniaus) VALUES ( :apaterus, :amaterus, :nombresus, :DNIus, :cargo, :correoe, :contraseniaus )");
           
              $insert->bindValue('apaterus',$_POST['apaterus']);
              $insert->bindValue('amaterus',$_POST['amaterus']);
              $insert->bindValue('nombresus',$_POST['nombresus']);
              $insert->bindValue('DNIus',$_POST['DNIus']);
              $insert->bindValue('cargo',$_POST['cargo']);
              $insert->bindValue('correoe',$_POST['correoe']);
              $insert->bindValue('contraseniaus',$_POST['contraseniaus']);
              $insert->execute();
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
              echo $e->getMessage();
            }

    }
```

Comment: Sí me di cuenta del error, muchas gracias.